# Taking a specific time from command line is not working

Tags: ruby, strftime

I have a program, which calculate many things. While I run the code by ruby code.rb everything is okay. The problem starts, when I want to run it by command line with additional option: ruby code.rb --time 201712121100.

The piece of problematic code is below:

```
include Options #here I have some options to choose, like --time

def calculate_p(time, mode)
   if mode
      calculator = calc1
   else
      calculator = calc2
   end
   calculate_t(time, calculator)
 end

def calculate_t(time, calculator)
   date_ymd = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
   time_hm  = time.strftime("%H%M")

   calculator
     .with(date_ymd, time_hm)
   .run do |result|
      if result.ok?
         result.stdout.pop.split.first
      else
        msgw("Program returned with errors.", :error)
        msgw("stdout: %s; stderr: %s" % [result.stdout, result.stderr], :error)
        false
      end
    end
 end

time  = Options.get('--time')
           .andand do |time_op|
              msgw('Taking time from command line arguments') do
                time_op.pop.andand
              end
            end || msgw('Calculating time for now.') do
              Time.now.utc
            end || abort
calc=calculate_p(time, mode)
```

`msgw` is just define to print messages.

`mode` takes `true` or `false` values.

I received an error:

> "`calculate_t`: undefined method `strftime` for `"201712121100":String` (`NoMethodError`)"

What am I doing wrong? Why using `Time.now.utc` is working while giving a specific time is not?

I also checked the solutions from here [Rails undefined method `strftime' for "2013-03-06":String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735591/rails-undefined-method-strftime-for-2013-03-06string)
and Date.parse() gives the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails undefined method \`strftime' for "2013-03-06":String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735591/rails-undefined-method-strftime-for-2013-03-06string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
time_op.pop.andand
```

`time_op` taken from the command line is a string, and you need a `Time` instance. The get it, use [`DateTime#strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime):

```
DateTime.strptime(time_op.pop, "%Y%m%d%H%M").to_time.andand
```

Comment: Changing the line to DateTime.strptime(time_op, "%Y%m%d%H%M").pop.andand does not help. It gives me "`strptime': no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)".  What is to_time in your example?

Comment: Updated. I misplaced  `pop`.

Comment: It works with: ruby code.rb --time 201712121100. But as sometimes I want to still execute it for current time by ruby code.rb it gives me "`strptime': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)". Why this is happening?